# Detecting user from winsock data?

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

For example i create socket using winsock under account named Admin. Is there any possibility to detect which user created that socket? I would like to write in my program: This socket was created by "Admin". i am using c++

Comment: Is this on client or server side ?

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are not securable objects (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379557(VS.85).aspx)) and so cannot have a security descriptor associated with them and so there's no way you can know the user account that 'created the socket'.

You could use [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928(v=VS.85).aspx) to get information about connections and then locate the PID of the process that created the socket; you could then decide to use something based on the process...

Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: when i get app socket using LSP, need to know the name of the user that ran the application which is using this socket

Comment: That's a subtly different question, you can use GetExtendedTCPTable for that, I expect; that will give you the PID then you can query the process for the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -o` should give you process IDs which created the socket; from there, you can find the process owner. If everything else fails, you could spawn netstat in a new process and parse the output.